# Regex: require "http://" in the front of this expression

Tags: regex

I am using a regex to try and validate URL's. The regex I have works very well but the only issue is that it validates URL's even if there is no `http://` in the front. I want it to only validate if the URL has `http://` in the front (even if it doesn't contain a www right after)

This is the regex I'm using:

```
((https?)\:\/\/)?([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,3})(\:[0-9]{2,5})?(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?
```

Comment: Don't validate URLs yourself.  Whatever language you are writing in undoubtedly has code that has already been written, tested and debugged.  What language are you using?

Comment: PHP, I've used `filter_var('http://example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` but it validates urls such as `http://example.c` and `http://example.comxx` which should not validate. What native PHP function would you suggest?

Comment: Why do you think those two shouldn't validate?

Comment: Because they aren't actual URL's? the '.com' part of the URL usually range from 2-4 chars. I know ICANN introduced some new domain extensions the past few years which can have up to 8 chars, but I do not think there are domain extensions of 1 char. Though I could be wrong I'm basing this stuff offa wikipedia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the second `?` from the left. It's acting as a quantifier to make the whole `http` section optional.

Comment: Thanks! For the lazy: this is the regex I'm using: `((https?)\:\/\/)([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?([a-z‌​0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,3})(\:[0-9]{2,5})?(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a‌​-z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?`

Answer (score 0):

Does making just the (s) optional work?

```
(http(s)?\:\/\/)?([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,3})(\:[0-9]{2,5})?(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?
```

After seeing the new answer, this would require http or https:

```
(http(s)?\:\/\/)([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,3})(\:[0-9]{2,5})?(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?
```

Comment: So you're just copying my answer then?